# If I already have eigenvectors and eigenvalues, how do I calculate T (x, y)?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know all the process to how to get eigenvectors and eigenvalues. But how do I know A(x, y) already having these values?

"Let T: R² → R² be a linear transformation that has eigenvectors (3, 1) and (−2, 1) associated with eigenvalues -2 and 3, respectively. Calculate T(x, y)."

Comment: What is A(x, y) supposed to be? What sort of function?

Answer (score 0):

Try writing an arbitrary $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ as a combination of the eigenvectors.
You want to write
$$
\pmatrix{x\\y} = c_1 \pmatrix{3\\1} + c_2 \pmatrix{-2\\1}.
$$
If you could find such $c_1, c_2$, then $A(x,y) = c_1 A(3,1) + c_2 A(-2,1)$.
We can either try to solve it by hand, or recognize that the above equation can be rewritten in matrix form
$$
\pmatrix{3 & -2\\1 & 1}\pmatrix{c_1 \\ c_2} = \pmatrix{x \\ y}
$$
so in general the answer is
$$
\pmatrix{c_1 \\ c_2} = \pmatrix{3 & -2\\1 & 1}^{-1}\pmatrix{x \\ y}.
$$
I assume that you are able to calculate a matrix inverse, so we find the answer is
$$
\pmatrix{c_1 \\ c_2} = \frac{1}{5}\pmatrix{1 & 2\\-1 & 3}\pmatrix{x \\ y}.
$$
Hence $c_1 = \frac{1}{5}(x+2y)$ and $c_2 = \frac{1}{5}(-x + 3y)$.
You can now plug in to $A(x,y) = c_1 A(3,1) + c_2 A(-2,1)$ to get your answer.